# Using Python to Pull SQL info into CSV and it comes out blank

Tags: python, mysql, sql, csv

I have a program I use to pull survey data from my site. I have it written in Python and it will take the info from the sql database, and download it into a csv file. It worked great, but out of nowhere it now is just a blank csv file with no information and has no size. Below is the program I use for the pull. I use python 3.7.4 right now.

```
import pymysql.cursors
import csv

import sshtunnel
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder

server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('ADDRESS', PORT),
    ssh_username='USERNAME',
    ssh_password='PASS',
    remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3306)
)

server.start()


def find_number(result, number):
    if str(number) in result['p4'].split(','):
        return 1
    if str(number) in result['p3'].split(','):
        return 2
    if str(number) in result['p2'].split(','):
        return 3
    if str(number) in result['p1'].split(','):
        return 4
    if str(number) in result['z'].split(','):
        return 5
    if str(number) in result['n1'].split(','):
        return 6
    if str(number) in result['n2'].split(','):
        return 7
    if str(number) in result['n3'].split(','):
        return 8
    if str(number) in result['n4'].split(','):
        return 9
    return 'not found: ' + str(number)

# Connect to the database
conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1',
                             user='USER',
                             password='PASS',
                             db='DBNAME',
                             charset='utf8mb4',
                       port=server.local_bind_port,
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

cursor = conn.cursor()


sql = "SELECT * FROM `surveys` order by id asc"
cursor.execute(sql)
results = cursor.fetchall()

output = {}
headers = []
comments = []

for result in results:
    headers.append(str(result['gender']) + '/' + str(result['birth_year']) + '/' + str(result['political_affiliation']) + '/' + str(result['religious_belief']) + '/' + str(result['ethnicity']) + '/' + str(result['location']))
    for nr in range(1, 37):
        if not nr in output:
            output[nr] = []
        nrr = find_number(result, nr)
        output[nr].append(nrr)
    comments.append(result['comments'])

writer = csv.writer(open("output5.csv", 'w', newline=''))
writer.writerow(headers)
for row in output:
    writer.writerow(output[row])
writer.writerow(comments)

conn.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be that `results` is returning a falsely value causing your for loop to be skipped. Have you tried adding a check around if there aren't any results?

```
...
results = cursor.fetchall()
if not results:
   raise RuntimeException('Cannot retrieve records from Database!')
```

Also, not sure if you know of [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) but you could also use it in your snippet to simplify a bit.

```
from collections import defaultdict
...
output = defaultdict(list)
for result in results:
 ...
 for nr in range(1, 37):
   output[nr].append(find_number(result, nr))
```

Comment: I didn't know the defualtdict, thank you. That does clean it up. The results issue though doesn't play through, if that makes sense. There is data in the sql table, so it doesn't through an exception or anything else. It connects, disconnects, and writes a file, but the file is just blank.